# Unique constraint on another table's column

Tags: sql, oracle, unique-constraint

I am creating two tables. First will be something like a verification step  while second will hold the data after verification passed.

So my first table is:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME_TEMP(
  SOME_NO number not null,
  GROUP_NAME VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
  PARENT_GROUP_ID INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (SOME_NO),
  CONSTRAINT FK_PARENT FOREIGN KEY(PARENT_GROUP_ID) REFERENCES 
  TABLE_NAME(ID),
  CONSTRAINT GROUP_NAME_UNIQUE UNIQUE (TABLE_NAME.GROUP_NAME, GROUP_NAME)
);
```

and second table which holds after verification passed successfully:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME(
  ID number not null,
  GROUP_NAME VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
  PARENT_GROUP_ID INT,
  PRIMARY KEY(ID),
  CONSTRAINT FK_PARENT FOREIGN KEY(PARENT_GROUP_ID) REFERENCES 
  TABLE_NAME(ID),
  CONSTRAINT GROUP_NAME_UNIQUE UNIQUE (GROUP_NAME),
  CONSTRAINT PK_ID_UNIQUE UNIQUE (ID)
  );
```

My problem is that GROUP_NAME must be unique in TABLE_NAME. So I need to have ensure that GROUP_NAME in TABLE_NAME_TEMP must not match existing values in TABLE_NAME. The way I have tried it `CONSTRAINT GROUP_NAME_UNIQUE UNIQUE (TABLE_NAME.GROUP_NAME, GROUP_NAME)` gives an error. Any advice?

Comment: Are you saying that you want a given GROUP_NAME to only appear once in either the TABLE_NAME_TEMP or TABLE_NAME, but not both? If so, it's not going to be possible to achieve that with a unique constraint, as those can only apply to a single table. Moreover, at some point you're going to have entries in both tables, since it's unusual to delete something before you've moved it over to the other table - you'd usually copy the row over and then delete. I wonder why you don't have a single table with a flag that says if it's verified or not?

Comment: @Boneist indeed this is what I mean, i see then i will go and try some work around procedures, thanks sir

Comment: What's the reason for the two separate tables, rather than a single table with a verified flag column? (Also, "sir" is a big assumption! *{;-) )

Comment: @Boneist separation is done due to the requirements of the system, i am not designing the whole system rather just a screen for learning purposes, sorry for 'sir' my bad )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot define a unique constraint across two separate tables.  That is not how unique constraints work.  You can do one of the following:

1. Fix the data model.  Having a unique constraint spread over two tables suggests an issue with the data model.  Put all the names in a single table which identifies the type of group.
2. Use a trigger.

Ideally, you could also add a unique constraint to a view.  Well, you *can* specify the unique constraint, but it is not enforced.  By default, the constraint is in "disable, no validate" mode.

Comment: Why does it indicate an "issue with the data model"? Suppose that I have a field in a table that should be unique for each "grandparent". I have a foreign key for my "parent", but not my "grandparent", so I can't use an index.

Comment: @DaveCousineau . . . Perhaps it is necessary to have two tables with the data and a unique constraint across them.  It is more typical to have a unique constraint within a table, because values *within a single entity* are typically unique, not *across* entities.

Comment: I guess what I mean is, properties of my parent (or ancestors) are effectively properties of me; as in, I have only one of each ancestral property. so, it's seems logical to need uniqueness up a hierarchy. examples are unique child names within a family, or unique codes within a season, etc. if it happens to be an immediate relative, then maybe you have a foreign key, but if the relative is 2 steps away, then you don't.

Answer (score 2):

`TABLE_NAME_TEMP` is some kind of staging table. In data warehouse environments it is common to have looser constraints on the staging table than we have on the final table (`TABLE_NAME` in your scenario).

> " first will be something like verification step, while second will hold the data after verification passed"

Checking that values of `TABLE_NAME_TEMP.GROUP_NAME` do not exist in `TABLE_NAME` seems like a verification step. If you do get duplicates in `TABLE_NAME_TEMP` you probably want to load them so you can investigate them without the load failing (depends on how you get data into the staging table).  Just delete them or filter them when it becomes time to load the final table.